My 3D python game has a bug named "Backface culling". How can i fix it?
So recently i've found this simple model projection code entirely written with python's pygame module.
It works very well untill you turn back at the object. The camera doesn't detect if you are infront or behind the object so it draws it anyway. So, when you pass throught the object, you pass in another dimension, where everything is inverted.
Test it and you will understand what i'm talking about.
Apparently this is a known problem named "Backface Culling", i've tested multiple ways to solve it but none of them works.
This would be very cool if someone that has experience in 3d programming could answer and give a resolution to my problem!
How to make the camera know that you are looking at an object with your front and not your back!!!
Here are the game's files:  (or just download them here)
main.py
from object_3d import *
from camera import *
from projection import *
import pygame as pg
import sys


class SoftwareRender:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.RES = self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = 1600, 900
        self.H_WIDTH, self.H_HEIGHT = self.WIDTH // 2, self.HEIGHT // 2
        self.running=True
        self.FPS = 60
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(self.RES)
        self.events=[]
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.create_objects()

    def create_objects(self):
        self.camera = Camera(self, [-5, 6, -55])
        self.projection = Projection(self)
        self.objects=[self.get_object_from_file('resources/t_34_obj.obj')]
        self.objects[0].rotate_y(-math.pi / 4)

    def get_object_from_file(self, filename):
        vertex, faces = [], []
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                if line.startswith('v '):
                    vertex.append([float(i) for i in line.split()[1:]] + [1])
                elif line.startswith('f'):
                    faces_ = line.split()[1:]
                    faces.append([int(face_.split('/')[0]) - 1 for face_ in faces_])
        return Object3D(self, vertex, faces)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(pg.Color('darkslategray'))
        
        for object in self.objects:
            object.draw()

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self.draw()
            self.camera.control()
            self.camera.mouse_control()

            self.events=pg.event.get()
            for i in self.events:
                if i.type == pg.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

            pg.display.set_caption(str(self.clock.get_fps()))
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.FPS)
        
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SoftwareRender()
    app.run()

camera.py
import pygame as pg
from matrix_functions import *

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, render, position):
        self.render = render
        self.position = np.array([*position, 1.0])
        self.forward = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
        self.up = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
        self.right = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.h_fov = math.pi / 3
        self.v_fov = self.h_fov * (render.HEIGHT / render.WIDTH)
        self.near_plane = 0.1
        self.far_plane = 100
        self.moving_speed = 1
        self.rotation_speed = 0.015

        self.anglePitch = 0
        self.angleYaw = 0
        self.angleRoll = 0

        self.old_ms_pos=None

        self.sandbox_mode=False
        self.grav=0.1
        self.jump_height=2
        self.hsp=0
        self.vsp=0

    def control(self):
        key = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pg.K_a]:
            self.position -= self.right * self.moving_speed
        if key[pg.K_d]:
            self.position += self.right * self.moving_speed
        if key[pg.K_w]:
            self.position += self.forward * self.moving_speed
        if key[pg.K_s]:
            self.position -= self.forward * self.moving_speed

        if self.sandbox_mode:
            if key[pg.K_q]:
                self.position += self.up * self.moving_speed
            if key[pg.K_e]:
                self.position -= self.up * self.moving_speed
        else:
            self.vsp-=self.grav

            if key[pg.K_SPACE]:
                self.vsp=self.jump_height

            self.position+=np.array([0, 1, 0, 0])*self.vsp
            if self.position[1]<0:
                self.position[1]=0

        if key[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.camera_yaw(-self.rotation_speed)
        if key[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.camera_yaw(self.rotation_speed)
        if key[pg.K_UP]:
            self.camera_pitch(-self.rotation_speed)
        if key[pg.K_DOWN]:
            self.camera_pitch(self.rotation_speed)

        if key[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
            self.render.running=False

    def mouse_control(self):
        mouse=pg.mouse.get_pressed()
        mouse_pos=pg.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_wheel_rel=0

        for e in self.render.events:
            if e.type==pg.MOUSEWHEEL and self.sandbox_mode==True:
                mouse_wheel_rel=e.y
            elif e.type==pg.KEYDOWN and e.key==pg.K_TAB:
                for idx, object in enumerate(self.render.objects):
                    self.render.objects[idx].draw_vertices=not object.draw_vertices

        if mouse[0] and self.old_ms_pos!=None:
            diff_x, diff_y=mouse_pos[0]-self.old_ms_pos[0], mouse_pos[1]-self.old_ms_pos[1]

            self.camera_yaw(diff_x*self.rotation_speed)
            self.camera_pitch(diff_y*self.rotation_speed)

        self.position+=self.forward*(self.moving_speed*mouse_wheel_rel)

        self.old_ms_pos=mouse_pos

    def camera_yaw(self, angle):
        self.angleYaw += angle

    def camera_pitch(self, angle):
        self.anglePitch += angle

    def axiiIdentity(self):
        self.forward = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
        self.up = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
        self.right = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])

    def camera_update_axii(self):
        # rotate = rotate_y(self.angleYaw) @ rotate_x(self.anglePitch)
        rotate = rotate_x(self.anglePitch) @ rotate_y(self.angleYaw)  # this concatenation gives right visual
        self.axiiIdentity()
        self.forward = self.forward @ rotate
        self.right = self.right @ rotate
        self.up = self.up @ rotate

    def camera_matrix(self):
        self.camera_update_axii()
        return self.translate_matrix() @ self.rotate_matrix()

    def translate_matrix(self):
        x, y, z, w = self.position
        return np.array([
            [1, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [-x, -y, -z, 1]
        ])

    def rotate_matrix(self):
        rx, ry, rz, w = self.right
        fx, fy, fz, w = self.forward
        ux, uy, uz, w = self.up
        return np.array([
            [rx, ux, fx, 0],
            [ry, uy, fy, 0],
            [rz, uz, fz, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])

matrix_functions.py
import math
import numpy as np


def translate(pos):
    tx, ty, tz = pos
    return np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [tx, ty, tz, 1]
    ])


def rotate_x(a):
    return np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, math.cos(a), math.sin(a), 0],
        [0, -math.sin(a), math.cos(a), 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])


def rotate_y(a):
    return np.array([
        [math.cos(a), 0, -math.sin(a), 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [math.sin(a), 0, math.cos(a), 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])


def rotate_z(a):
    return np.array([
        [math.cos(a), math.sin(a), 0, 0],
        [-math.sin(a), math.cos(a), 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])


def scale(n):
    return np.array([
        [n, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, n, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, n, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
    ])

projection.py
import math
import numpy as np


class Projection:
    def __init__(self, render):
        NEAR = render.camera.near_plane
        FAR = render.camera.far_plane
        RIGHT = math.tan(render.camera.h_fov / 2)
        LEFT = -RIGHT
        TOP = math.tan(render.camera.v_fov / 2)
        BOTTOM = -TOP

        m00 = 2 / (RIGHT - LEFT)
        m11 = 2 / (TOP - BOTTOM)
        m22 = (FAR + NEAR) / (FAR - NEAR)
        m32 = -2 * NEAR * FAR / (FAR - NEAR)
        self.projection_matrix = np.array([
            [m00, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, m11, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, m22, 1],
            [0, 0, m32, 0]
        ])

        HW, HH = render.H_WIDTH, render.H_HEIGHT
        self.to_screen_matrix = np.array([
            [HW, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, -HH, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [HW, HH, 0, 1]
        ])

object_3d.py  --Here is the problem
import pygame as pg
from matrix_functions import *
from numba import njit


@njit(fastmath=True)
def any_func(arr, a, b):
    return np.any((arr == a) | (arr == b))


class Object3D:
    def __init__(self, render, vertices='', faces=''):
        self.render = render
        self.vertices = np.array(vertices)
        self.faces = faces
        self.translate([0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001])

        self.font = pg.font.SysFont('Arial', 30, bold=True)
        self.color_faces = [(pg.Color('orange'), face) for face in self.faces]
        self.movement_flag, self.draw_vertices = True, True
        self.label = ''

    def draw(self):
        self.screen_projection()
        self.movement()

    def movement(self):
        if self.movement_flag:
            self.rotate_y(-(pg.time.get_ticks() % 0.005))

    def screen_projection(self):
        vertices = self.vertices @ self.render.camera.camera_matrix()
        vertices = vertices @ self.render.projection.projection_matrix
        vertices /= vertices[:, -1].reshape(-1, 1)
        vertices[(vertices > 2) | (vertices < -2)] = 0
        vertices = vertices @ self.render.projection.to_screen_matrix
        vertices = vertices[:, :2]

        for index, color_face in enumerate(self.color_faces): #Here it draws the polygon almost without any checks, just a small check if the object is on screen
            color, face = color_face
            polygon = vertices[face]

            if not any_func(polygon, self.render.H_WIDTH, self.render.H_HEIGHT):
                pg.draw.polygon(self.render.screen, color, polygon, 1)
                if self.label:
                    text = self.font.render(self.label[index], True, pg.Color('white'))
                    self.render.screen.blit(text, polygon[-1])

        if self.draw_vertices:
            for vertex in vertices:
                if not any_func(vertex, self.render.H_WIDTH, self.render.H_HEIGHT):
                    pg.draw.circle(self.render.screen, pg.Color('white'), vertex, 2)

    def translate(self, pos):
        self.vertices = self.vertices @ translate(pos)

    def scale(self, scale_to):
        self.vertices = self.vertices @ scale(scale_to)

    def rotate_x(self, angle):
        self.vertices = self.vertices @ rotate_x(angle)

    def rotate_y(self, angle):
        self.vertices = self.vertices @ rotate_y(angle)

    def rotate_z(self, angle):
        self.vertices = self.vertices @ rotate_z(angle)


class Axes(Object3D):
    def __init__(self, render):
        super().__init__(render)
        self.vertices = np.array([(0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)])
        self.faces = np.array([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)])
        self.colors = [pg.Color('red'), pg.Color('green'), pg.Color('blue')]
        self.color_faces = [(color, face) for color, face in zip(self.colors, self.faces)]
        self.draw_vertices = False
        self.label = 'XYZ'


Folder: resources/t_34_obj.obj WARNING IT'S VERY LONG SO DOWNLOAD IT HERE

Apparently this is a known problem named "Backface Culling" If it's well-known enough to have a specific name, then surely there are also known strategies to solve it.  So ... use one of those.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
